# Can't pass in interface to controller without throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface-injection

I created a service class 'TeacherService' with an interface that I want to pass it into my controller's constructor, but when I try there is an error in one of the constructors

As soon as I type a comma into the constructors parameters it red unerlines

> new TeacherRepository()

saying it can't resolve the constructor.
Here is the code.

```
public class TeacherController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITeacherRepository teacherRepository;
    private  readonly ITeacherService teacherService;

    // If you are using Dependency Injection, you can delete the following constructor
    public TeacherController() : this(new TeacherRepository())
    {
    }

    public TeacherController(ITeacherRepository teacherRepository, ITeacherService teacherService)
    {
        this.teacherRepository = teacherRepository;
        this.teacherService = teacherService;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public TeacherController() : this(new TeacherRepository())
```

You are calling the second constructor that expects two parameters with just one. Add the default `TeacherService` for it to compile.

Comment: I got it! I passed (new TeacherService) into this()